# Loop through children of ol tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have the following html structure:

```
<ol>
  <li>...</li>
  <div>...</div>
  <li>...</li>
</ol>
```

When I do the following:

```
for e in doc.find('ol').children:
    print(e.text)
```

I get the two **li** elements but not the **div**

What can I do to get all of them in the correct order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script ist working, you could adjust it a bit and just print the text of the tags:

```
for e in soup.find('ol').children:
    if e.name:
        print(e.text)
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<ol>
  <li>...li1</li>
  <div>...div</div>
  <li>...li2</li>
</ol>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for e in soup.find('ol').children:
    if e.name:
        print(e.text)
```

###### Output

```
...li1
...div
...li2
```

Comment: No, strangely it's the other way around! I'd expect to get all elements, but I don't get the div.

Comment: And I want to get the li and the div aswell

Comment: sorry had read it the other way round, so your script works fine for the example.

Comment: You're right, the get request did not return the data I thought it did